# Create a username with C language

Tags: c, arrays, string, character

I have a to create a program where the user should create a username with minimum of 8 characters and maximum of 12 characters. What should I use for this one? I was thinking to use an array but I am not really sure of how I will set it with minimum of 8 characters, so maybe an array will not work. Is there any other option that I could use???

Comment: You can use `strlen()` to get the length of a string and check if that’s less than 8.

Comment: thank you i will try this! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `do-while` to check the input.
So it will loop everytime the input is wrong

```
do{
    printf("Username : ");
    //scanf here
}while( strlen(your variable) < 8 || strlen(your variable) > 12 );
```

Everytime the user input username with less than 8 character or more than 12 character, it will ask to input again